# OSX Slack standalone client is continuously reconnecting for one of several workspaces

Tags: slack

This is a question with the answer. Hopefully, it will save someone else some searching.

My OSX Slack standalone client was stuck in a reconnecting loop but for only one of my workspaces. I rebooted my machine and re-installed Slack, and yet the issue persisted.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
In the menu, go to

> Help -> Troubleshooting -> Clear Cache and Restart

After the restart, the problem went away.